# Step of the proof that $\mathbb{RP}^{3} \cong SO(3)$

Tags: linear-algebra, differential-geometry, lie-groups, quaternions, projective-space

i would like to prove that the matrix representation of the map $\phi:\mathbb{H}\to \mathbb{H}$, where $\phi(v)=pvp^{*}$ is an element of $SO(3)$,with respect to the basis $(\textbf{i},\textbf{j},\textbf{k})$ for the set of imaginary quatérnions, here $p$ is a unit quaternion.

I calculated $\phi$ in the elements of the base ($\textbf{i}$,$\textbf{j}$,$\textbf{k}$), here $p=(a,b)$ is a unit quaternion. Then

$\phi(\textbf{i})=(|a|^{2}-|b|^{2})\textbf{i}-2ab\textbf{k}$

$\phi(\textbf{j})=(-\bar{b}a-b\bar{a})\textbf{1}+(a^{2}+b^{2})\textbf{k}$

$\phi(\textbf{k})=(b\bar{a}+\bar{b}a)\textbf{i}+(a^{2}-b^{2})\textbf{k}$

the result of $\phi(\textbf{j})$ confuses me because there is a term that does not belong to the base $(-\bar{b}a-b\bar{a})\text{1}$

Any  tips?

Comment: If you are representing a quaternion as a pair of complex numbers $(a, b) = a + \mathbf{j}b$, then $(a, b)^* = (\overline{a}, -b)$. So I don't think that $\overline{b}$ should show up in your equations. I may be missing something: if so, please show more of your working in the question.

Comment: You almost certainly computed $\phi(j)$ incorrectly, for $j 1 j^{*} = jj^{*} = 1$, so $\phi(j)$ leaves the $1$-axis fixed, and hence leaves the 3-plane of pure vector quaternions -- those orthogonal to the $1$-axis --- setwise fixed as well, but your version of $\phi(j)$ sends $i$ to something with a nonzero component along the $1$ axis.

Comment: @RobArthan yes, i am representing a quaternion as a pair of complex numbers.

Comment: @JohnHughes i don't understand the computation, record that $v\to pvp^{*}$, where $v$ is a imaginary quaternion and $p$ is a unit quaternion. The basis $(\textbf{i},\textbf{j},\textbf{k})$  where $\textbf{i}=(i,0)$,$\textbf{j}=(0,1)$, and $\textbf{k}=(0,i)$

Comment: We can't help you find the error in your calculation if you don't show us the details. I think you may find the representation of a quaternion as $\alpha + \beta i + \gamma j + \delta k$ with $\alpha$, $\beta$, $\gamma$ and $\delta$ real more appropriate for this problem, since you are, after all, trying to represent conjugation by the unit quaternion $p$ as a $3\times3$ matrix of real numbers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This answer is just an expansion of what anomaly pointed out, since you seem confused by his answer in the comments.

This is in reality a problem about linear algebra only:

Your map $\phi$ is clearly a isometry in $\mathbb{H}$, since 
\begin{align*}
\langle pvp^*, pv'p^*\rangle &=\operatorname{Re}(pvp^*pv'^*p^*) \\
&=\operatorname{Re}(pvv'^*p^*) \\
&\stackrel{!}{=}\operatorname{Re}(v'^*p^*pv) \\
&=\operatorname{Re}(v'^*v) \\
&=\langle v,v' \rangle.
\end{align*}
Important: The equation $(!)$ is *not* using commutativity of the elements. It is using the fact that $\operatorname{Re}(xy)=\operatorname{Re}(yx)$.

Since $\phi(1)=1$, it thus follows that $\phi$ restricts to the orthogonal complement of $1$, which is a three-dimensional inner product space. Given any inner-product equipped vector space of dimension $n$, "its" $SO_V$ (let's call it that for the sake of clarity), i.e., the set of linear maps such that $\langle Av,Aw \rangle=\langle v,w \rangle$ (let's call this equation $(1)$) is always isomorphic to $SO(n)$, which you seem to define as a matrix group, via the matricial representation with respect to a fixed orthonormal basis $\mathcal{B}$ in $V$. This is simply a consequence of the fact that the matrix group $SO(n)$ can be characterized as the group of those matrices with orthonormal columns in the standard inner-product of $\mathbb{R}^n$. The map 
\begin{align*}
SO_V &\to SO(n)  \\
A &\mapsto A_{\mathcal{B}},
\end{align*}
which sends a linear map to its matricial representation w.r.t $\mathcal{B}$ is obviously an isomorphism (the fact that it sends indeed to $SO(n)$ is immediate from equation $(1)$ and the characterization of the collumns of the matricial representation of a linear map)*. This is what you are doing when you say "$\phi$ (...) with respect to the basis $(i,j,k)$": just taking $\mathcal{B}:=\{i,j,k\}$.

So, to sum up: from the fact that $\phi(1)=1$ and $\phi$ is an isometry, we get that $\phi|_{1^{\perp}}:1^{\perp} \to 1^{\perp}$ is a well-defined map, which is by definition an element of $SO_{1^{\perp}}$. The base $\{i,j,k\}$ is obviously orthonormal, and thus the map above indeed sends us to $SO(3)$.

*-  Just for the sake of completeness, letting $\mathcal{B}=\{f_1,\cdots,f_n\}$, the computation is :
\begin{align*}
\sum_{k=1}^na_{ki}a_{kj}&=\langle \sum_{l} a_{li}f_l, \sum_{m} a_{mj}f_m \rangle \\
&=\langle A f_i, Af_j \rangle \\
&=\langle f_i, f_j \rangle \\
&=\delta_{ij}.
\end{align*}

Comment: Aloizio good answer, thanks again

Comment: Hi @Aloizio, i would like to know why the map, $\phi: S\to SO(3)$ (where $S$ are unit quaternions), is a group homomorphism. I prove there is a group action by a Lie Group $S$ in $1^{\perp}$, $\theta(q,v)=qvq*$, then this action índuces a homomorphism between $S$ and $Sym(1^{\perp})$, note that $Sym(1^{\perp})$ is not empty because $\phi|_{1^{\perp}} \in Sym (1^{\perp})$.

Comment: The fact that $\phi_{1^{\perp}}$ has matricial representation in $1^{\perp}$ with respect the base $(i,j,k)$ is in $SO(3)$ implies that $SO(3) =Sym(1^{\perp})$?

Answer (score 3):

Why are you computing $\phi$ explicitly? Just note that $\phi$ fixes $1^\perp\subset \mathbb{H}$ and clearly leaves the inherited norm invariant; that is, it lies in $SO(1^\perp) = SO(3)$.

Comment: i showed that $\phi$ is an isometrie when restricted to $1^{\perp}$. But i don't understand : (1) $SO(3)=SO(1^{\perp})$. (2) Why (1)  prove that the matrix representation with respect to the basis $(\textbf{i},\textbf{j},\textbf{k})$ for $1^{\perp}$ is an element of $SO(3)$.

Comment: The answer for my questions is because elements of $SO(1^{\perp})$ has the same property of $SO(3)$,i.e, preserves inner product?

Comment: $SO(3)$ is the group of orientation-preserving automorphisms of $\mathbb{R}^3$ preserving the inner product. (I didn't address the determinant above, but it's easy to verify that the induced maps lie in $SO$ rather than just $O$.)